# How to set both linear-gradient and background image in a specific div using styles in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to set linear-gradient as well as the background image on a specific div using styles in Reactsjs

I am able to get either of them, I mean to say either image or linear-gradient but not both at the same time

The image is going to overlap with the linear gradient

I tried below solution :

```css
 leftAdArea: {
      width: 380,
      height: 580,
      background: 'url(https://www.mahealthcare.com/assets/images/clinic/NursePhone.jpg) no-repeat , linear-gradient(135deg, #50A684 30%, #115E67 90%)',
      }
```

Suggest me to to do this kind of stuff where I can use the image as well as linear-gradient on an image

Thanks

Comment: Try putting the `linear-gradient` before the `url`

Comment: @MarcHjorth already tried the same

Comment: What is it showing? And try using `rgba` values instead of hex+`30%`

Comment: try changing background property to background-image.---background-image:linear-gradient(135deg, #50A68480 30%, #115E6780 90%), url('https://www.mahealthcare.com/assets/images/clinic/NursePhone.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. I think you forgot to add double quotes inside URL("link").
I have used hexa+alpha value in linear-gradient ( #50A684 - 80 ) 80 is 50% alpha.

```
     leftAdArea:{
   width: 200px,
   height: 200px,
   background-image:"linear-gradient(135deg, #50A68480 30%, #115E6780 90%), url('https://www.mahealthcare.com/assets/images/clinic/NursePhone.jpg')";
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:50%;
   }
```

Comment: @vssadineniI tried using double quotes, thus i solved my problem in another way, Thanks

Comment: would you be kind to share the solution. just for the record sake.

Answer (score 0):

```
leftAdArea: {
  width: 380,
  height: 580,
  background:`url(obj.image) no-repeat, linear-gradient(135deg, #50A684 30%, #115E67 90%)`,
}
```

used backtick instead of qoutes