# Is it possible to use linear-gradient on top of a landing image in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, inline

I am wishing to add a gradient to a landing page image.

I see examples in CSS using background ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412372/how-to-set-both-linear-gradient-and-background-image-in-a-specific-div-using-sty)) but I am curious if it is possible to add it inline.

I appreciate any critiques, thank you!

```
import React from 'react';
import city from '../images/city-buildings.jpg'

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='home'>
      <img
        src={city}
        alt="city buildings looking up"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        backgroundImage="linear-gradient(to right, #4880EC, #019CAD)".  <------------- this line
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Apply style to parent div -> `style={{ background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #430089, #82ffa1)'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a linear gradient over an image this code worked for me:

Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import city from '../images/city-buildings.jpg'

const style = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  opacity: '0.8'
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <img
          src={city}
          style={style}
          alt="city buildings looking up"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Component.css

```
.home {
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
```